# Vaadin widgetset path is changed after updating to 7.7.0

Tags: java, vaadin

In my Vaadin application, I have my own widgetset specified like below in `web.xml`

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
        <param-value>com.foo.bar.AppWidgetSet</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

And, I had placed my `AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml` file in `src/main/java/com/foo/bar/AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml`

This setup worked fine until I upgraded to vaadin 7.7.0 (from 7.6.8). After upgrade, I got following error, when I try to access the app through a browser.

```
INFO: Requested resource [/VAADIN/widgetsets/AppWidgetset/AppWidgetset.nocache.js] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
```

It seems like vaadin is looking for a different location for the widgetset, so I placed my `AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml` in the root of the classpath (`src/main/java/AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml`) and re-built the app.

Then it worked again.

Is specifying the widgetset as an init param no longer available? Do I have to place the widgetset xml in the root of the classpath itself?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues after upgrading my Vaadin application from 7.6.8 to 7.7.2. I've noticed that package under src/main/resources started to multiply recursively :

Below was the state with version 7.6.8, prior updating POM to 7.7.7 :

- src/main/resources
- myPackage
- MyAppWidgetset.gwt.xml

After updating POM to 7.7.7, under "myPackage" appeared new "myPackage" with xml file ! Just to emphasize that after every rebuild, those folders constantly creating and creating, so after 4th build there are more than 10 subfolders !

- src/main/resources
- ....myPackage
- ........**myPackage**
- ................**MyAppWidgetset.gwt.xml**
- ................................**myPackage**
- ................................................**MyAppWidgetset.gwt.xml**
- ...
- MyAppWidgetset.gwt.xml

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if there is a bug in 7.7.2 as regards custom widgetsets. First, check if you really need them. With no client side custom widgets, just forget any widgetset annotations or any related web.xml parametrization and let Vaadin make use of its new default AppWidgetset. If not, consider refactoring and converting custom client stuff into separate projects, installed in local Maven repo and then used via dependency, still not putting any own gwt.xml anywhere in main project's path. Finally, if none of above may be used (as in my case, too), just wait for bug fix in 7.7.3.

See: https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/20320

As I noticed, new 7.7.2 plugin does not put anything into source (i.e. /VAADIN/widgetsets), but stores compiled JS directly in output artifact and war archive. So, the workaround for @Lahiru Chandima could be not rely entirely on new, ascetic 7.7.2 plugin and make use of some old elements like `<webappDirectory>` and/or `<hostedWebapp>`, mentioning `${basedir}/src...` locations.

For @dobrivoje I'd recommend doing compilation as needed, then remove surprisingly created unnecessary (nested) packages and xml file and forget client compilation for some time (is it really needed in every build?) by commenting out Maven goals:

```
<!-- goal>update-widgetset</goal>
<goal>compile</goal -->
```